# Trouble installing and loading "mlrMBO" package in R

Tags: r, macos

So when I install the package, R returns the following error message:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mlrMBO’
```

But It then says the package has non-zero exit status and is in

```
‘/private/var/folders/b_/xwf1w6cn769_2gq06fntysxm0000gn/T/RtmpCGAr62/downloaded_packages’
```

When I load the package 
    library(mlrMBO) 
It says the package doesn't exist.

I've tried many different methods like using this code

```
install.packages('mlr', repo='http://cran.fiocruz.br/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things you could try:

- Make sure you don't have any Umlauts (ö,ä,ü, å) in your path, i.e. your User-folder, if you're running on windows.
- Install devtools `install.package("devtools)`
- clear data in `\AppData\Local\Temp\`

Comment: OP is on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

That package requires compiling C code, for which you have to install the Xcode developer tools.

Per Housemd's [answer at Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path/254381):

> Open Terminal, and run the following:
>
> ```
> xcode-select --install
> ```
>
> This will download and install xcode developer tools and fix the problem. The problem is that one needs to explicitly agree to the license agreement.
>
> I found the solution in this question, Command Line Tools not working.

Once you've done that, run `install.packages` again.